# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “”

Tags: java, android, exception, numbers

The question is duplicate but I can't find a proper solution so please help me out with this,

I have to convert the credit card number(from edittext) to int.
Credit card number like : "3333 3333 3333 3333"
I removed white space using `String removeWhiteSpace = cardNumEt.getText().toString().replace(" ", "");`
Than converted to int like :

```
  try
            {
                int nIntFromET = Integer.parseInt(removeWhiteSpace);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
               Log.e("exptn",e.toString());
            }
```

but unfortunately it's giving me exception :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3333333333333333"
```

Comment: Your number is too big to be parsed as an `int`, use `long`

Comment: I can't send long value to server. @jAC

Comment: Then you need to do something to change the fact that you can't use a `long` on your server.  A credit card number will simply not fit in an `int`.  Perhaps you could just use a `String`.

Comment: Well then you can't use larger numbers...

Comment: Your server guy seems to messed up . Credit Card number should be a String always not an integer. we take integer value usually if some math operation to be perform on it . Just change the type to String .

Comment: [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: First of all credit card must be in string as according to the format of the credit card number, and as according to the data you use long data type can store whole numbers from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. @Himani

Answer (score 2):

The int type in Java can be used to represent any whole number from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

Your value is above the maximum positive integer.
But you can use instead long and BigInteger

```java
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            int nIntFromET = Integer.parseInt("2147483647");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```